# How can I DllImport a file from resources using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, dllimport

Is there any way in VB.NET to DllImport a dll file from the resources?

I really don't want to add the dll with the executable path.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed a DLL into an executable:

[Jeffrey Richter: Excerpt #2 from CLR via C#, Third Edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx?Redirected=true)

> Many applications consist of an EXE file that depends on many DLL
>   files. When deploying this application, all the files must be
>   deployed. However, there is a technique that you can use to deploy
>   just a single EXE file. First, identify all the DLL files that your
>   EXE file depends on that do not ship as part of the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework itself. Then add these DLLs to your Visual Studio project.
>   For each DLL file you add, display its properties and change its
>   “Build Action” to “Embedded Resource.” This causes the C# compiler to
>   embed the DLL file(s) into your EXE file, and you can deploy this one
>   EXE file.
>
> At runtime, the CLR won’t be able to find the dependent DLL
>   assemblies, which is a problem. To fix this, when your application
>   initializes, register a callback method with the AppDomain’s
>   ResolveAssembly event.

Comment: I added the sqlite.dll to the resources, but couldn't find the Build Action from the properties.
And this is the callback with the AppDomain code i used:
  http://pastebin.com/Rm3MfE9Y
Sorry had to use pastebin because text was too long.
Still not working tho

Comment: Build Action is right there in properties. It's hard to miss.

Comment: Would the downvoter please leave a comment. It's the right thing to do.